# Cleaner way to wait for a promise to be resolved before assigning its value to an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, promise

I want to wait for a promise to be resolved before assigning its value to an object. I have some ideas on how to do this, doing the assignment inside of the .then for example, but I want to know what's the best practice.

Pseudo code:

```
orderData = [
    {
    'productId':'69',
    'name': 'honey'
    },
    {
    'productId':'96',
    'name': 'horse'
    }]

async function post(orderData){
    for (let i in orderData){

    //getting extra information about the products
        var productData = await axios.get('/' + $(orderData[i].product_id))
        .then(response => {return response})

        items[i] = {
        "product_code": orderData[i].product_id,
        "name": orderData[i].product_name,

        //does this work
        "cfop": await productData.cfop,
        "icms_situacao_tributaria": await productData.icms
```

items.[0].cfop or icms to not be null

Comment: `.then(response => {return response})` effectively does nothing

Comment: that's not actual code, I just wanted to represent productData as a promise

Comment: now I got what you meant, sry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either awaiting or assigning within the promise chain will work, mostly depends how you need to use promise results, what variables in scope, etc... Here's a [source](https://javascript.info/promise-chaining) I found helpful when first learning the subtle differences between `async/await`, Promises, and `try/catch`, and how they work together.

```
async function post(orderData) {
  const items = [];
  for (let i in orderData){

    //getting extra information about the products
    var productData = await axios.get('/' + $(orderData[i].product_id));

    items.push({
      "product_code": orderData[i].product_id,
      "name": orderData[i].product_name,
      "cfop": productData.cfop, // no need to await here, you have the resolved value
      "icms_situacao_tributaria": productData.icms,
      ...
    });
  ...
}
```

or

```
async function post(orderData) {
  const items = [];
  for (let i in orderData){
    await axios.get('/' + $(orderData[i].product_id));
      .then(productData => {
        items.push({
          "product_code": orderData[i].product_id,
          "name": orderData[i].product_name,
          "cfop": productData.cfop, // no need to await here, you have the resolved value
          "icms_situacao_tributaria": productData.icms,
          ...
        });
      });
  ...
}
```

or using map

```
function post(orderData) {
  return orderData.map(async (data) => {
    return await axios.get('/' + $(data.product_id));
      .then(productData => ({
          "product_code": data.product_id,
          "name": data.product_name,
          "cfop": productData.cfop, // no need to await here, you have the resolved value
          "icms_situacao_tributaria": productData.icms,
          ...
        });
      );
  });

  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `.then` when using `await`. `await` waits for a promise to be resolved and then extracts the value from the promise. `axios.get` already returns a promise (based on [the first example in the axios documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios)), so there is no reason to use `.then`.

Async/await is a newer and cleaner language feature allows promises to run in a synchronous manner, allowing you to replace `.then` and `.catch`. You should not be using `.then` inside your async function. Take a look at [this short example from Google](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/async-functions#example_logging_a_fetch) for more info on how async/await cleans up regular promise code.

Removing `.then(response => {return response})` has the same output.

`var productData = await axios.get('/' + $(orderData[i].product_id));`

Comment: No problem! Please mark the reply as an answer to help anyone else who has the same question :)

Comment: sry if I'm being dumb but, do these awaits actually work? I wrote them as sudo code

Comment: `async/await` is not the same thing as ES6 Promises.  Promises are more similar to `try/catch`, as each Promise is implicitly wrapped in a `try/catch`.  `async/await` allows javascript to synchronously handle otherwise asynchronous code.

Comment: @Lordie yes, await is valid syntax.

Comment: @DrewReese thank you for the clarification, I will edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const axios = { get: (p) => Promise.resolve({ data: { cfop: 42, icms: 42 } }) }
const Axios = { all: (p) => Promise.all(p) }

// above is for the purpose of the demo

const orderData = [
  { 'productId': '69', 'name': 'honey' },
  { 'productId': '96', 'name': 'horse' }
];

function getProduct({ name, productId }) {
  return axios.get(`/${productId}`).then(res => ({
    "product_code": productId,
    "name": name,
    "cfop": res.data.cfop,
    "icms_situacao_tributaria": res.data.icms
  }));
}

async function post(orderData) {
  console.log({ items: await Axios.all(orderData.map(getProduct)) });
}

post(orderData)
```